# Magento [Payment Method]=> [PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution] is disabled on backend

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7. You can clearly see following image that i selected Payment Method -> PayPal Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition (Included Express Checkout). Under Required Settings [Enable this Solution] = No I want it replace with Yes but this field is disabled. I tried hard, My Payment Module is also enabled, I cleared cache. But in vain So please help me.Let me show you the problem Image:   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't become available to enable until you've filled in all of the required parameters to make it work correctly.  For example, if you don't have your credentials filled in it won't allow you to enable it.

Comment: Andrew Angell: Dear are u sure about that.

Comment: Yes.  I'm actually on 1.7.0.2 which is slightly different than what you're showing here because they've removed the word Website and are just calling it PayPal Payments Pro now.  When I go into my Payments Pro section the option to enable it is grayed out just like you originally showed, but as soon as I fill out all of the credentials it becomes available.

Comment: ok dear, let me check, I am asking about info from my client and I will put that info in it. If answer is correct i will mark you correct.